# Team City build agent work dir not getting changed

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I want to change the build dir of team city build agent to:

```
E://MY_PROJECT_SVN
```

While installing the build agent I set the same but it diaplays C://buildAgent/work in TeamCity web ui due to which my build fails.

My buildAgent.properties file shows

> workDir=E\:\\MY_PROJECT_SVN

And buildAgent.dist.properties file shows

> workDir=E://MY_PROJECT_SVN

But I get following error when I run team city

> Failed to start MSBuild.exe. Failed to find project file at path:
>   C:\BuildAgent\work\3ac16e0b4e3af05b\Modules\SIM5.sln

Because of wrong working dir

Comment: What is the checkout directory declared in the target definition ?

Comment: @Biswajit_86 What do you mean by target definition?

Answer (score 1):

The buildAgent.dist.properties is indeed just an example, but the solution is something you almost had; you need to put this into the buildAgent.properties:

> workDir=E:/MY_PROJECT_SVN

**Update:**

It should be noted that on TeamCity 7.0 the workDir seemingly can't be on a separate disk; it runs most of the way through the build and then fails.  However, using a junction to point from the local (default) folder to the E: drive will work.  The tempDir can be pointed to a remote disk though.

Answer (score 0):

The file buildAgent.dist.properties is not used, it is just an example.  So don't worry about the contents of that file.

What you have set in buildAgent.properties is what matters.  What is happening for you is the agent is reverting to the default location for the working directory.

This means that for some reason it is not able to read or parse the buildAgent.properties file.  Make 100% certain that the entire file has no errors in it.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Agent+Configuration

Making any change to this file and saving it should cause the build agent to reboot automatically and reload the new config once it has restarted.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2007/10/configuration-files-editing-without-teamcity-restart/

Comment: weirdly i can change the temp dir but not work dir. tried absolute and relative paths. seems that work dir has to start with c:\TeamCity or else it rejects any changes

Comment: I can verify that I have set the workDir for all my TeamCity agents to a different location and this has worked fine.  I have the line:
workDir=D:\TC

Not sure what issue you are having specifically though.  If you remove any sensitive data from the buildAgent.properties file and post it here I can have a look and try to find the error...

Comment: thanks, i moved on w/out changing the folder but I literally spent an hour on this and couldn't change it to anything but c:\TeamCity\...  maybe it's my version of build agent or dependency on some other setting.. but i gave up

Answer (score 0):

To build on paul-f-wood's answer:

Teamcity 9.1.6 also has the "feature" where the work directory cannot be on a different drive.   I tried several permutations of the temp and work dir, and the only ones that stuck were with the work dir on the same drive as the root teamcity  folder.  However as paul said, using a junction works like a charm.

cmd:  rm C:\BuildAgent\work

cmd:  mklink /J C:\BuildAgent\work E:\MY_PROJECT_SVN